# Scrolling Win32 Dialog with child edit boxes

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, scrollable

I have a Win32 windows dialog in C++ with several elements. Currently there is a Rich Edit control at the bottom  and a tree list view at the top right, created in a resource editor. I've programmatically added other edit boxes and checkboxes to it in the space at the top left. However, depending on context, sometimes there isn't enough space. So, I want to create some sort of "window" in the dialog, with  scrollbars, into which I attach all my edit controls and checkboxes, so it will scroll if necessary, and of course clip out, pixel perfect, the ones that are outside the range of the scrollbars.

I've tried creating a parent "edit" window, with a scrollbar, and adding all the child edit windows and checkboxes to it, but it has draw problems, doesn't allow me to click on my edit controls, and doesn't clip. Obviously it's not meant to be done quite like this.

So, is this possible? Do I have to handle the scrollbars myself ? Or is there some magic windows setup that will allow it...?

Thanks

Shaun Southern

Comment: It'll probably be easier to handle the scrollbars yourself and adjust the positions of the controls based on the scroll position.

Comment: Yes, I found sample code and created a new "class", with its own dialogproc, and attached all my buttons to that. It clips fine, and I handle the scroll bars myself, then move each of the buttons by the scroll amount. Not sure if I could add a single item to the new "pane" class, then add my buttons to there, then move that item, but this seems to work, although I'm still getting redraw/flickering problems...